# 2k views in 12 hours: is there a glitch?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Not sure if meta is the right place for this: Did this question 
[If I gain, then someone else loses. Correct?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/if-i-gain-then-someone-else-loses-correct)

 really get 2k views in 12 hours or is this a glitch? If it is not a glitch, does anybody have an idea what is going on? (E.g. :Someone is obsessive, it pops up on google, etc.)

Comment: Maybe it was in the hot network questions? That would also explain the strange answers.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBob Also explains a lot of the low rep answers.

Comment: Is anybody else a little disappointed that people might think that question is representative of economics.se questions, or of economists more generally?

Comment: The question has a score of 9 and 12 answers, partly from users with (relatively) high reputation. Is this a sign of disapointment?

Comment: I agree with André. Despite the popularity of the question the answer with the highest score is quite detailed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select count(*) from HAProxyLogs.dbo.LogsLastTwoDays 
where Host = 'economics.stackexchange.com'   
  and Uri = '/questions/5913/if-i-gain-then-someone-else-loses-correct'
  and IsPageView = 1
```

> 3236

Yep, seems legit. I checked our traffic logs and there are over 3,000 views in the last 21 hours since the question has been posted. (I did not check IPs, so this isn't 100% accurate for an actual *view* count, but it's close enough. There were a lot.)

The top referrer appears to be Stack Overflow, followed by `NULL` (read: we don't know), followed by stackexchange.com. My guess would be that the question made it into the Hot Network Questions list and did quite well at attracting views.